# Getting error : open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, universal-image-loader, permission-denied

This is the error I'm getting while running my app in Android Studio 2.1.3

[image]

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"....
```

listadapter exteds from base adapter getview code paste

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(position == 0){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, null);
        }else{
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        }
        //convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // ImageLoader class instance
        //ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader();
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());

    if (holder.imageView != null) {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

ImageDownloaderTask.java

```
public class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }

    if (imageViewReference != null) {
        ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
            }
        }

    }
}

private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL uri = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return null;
        }

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return bitmap;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

and the following files are (ImageLoader.java,FileCache.java, MemoryCache.java) from the below url 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

How can I solve this? Please help me, Advance Thanks

Comment: `EACCESS (Permission Denied)` - that's your issue right there. After 6.0, just declaring permissions isn't enough for your app to use them. You need to [request the appropriate permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), *every time*, to ensure that you have access to the dangerous permissions your app requires.